# How to customize youtube player?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have an app that lets users upload youtube links and in the show action dynamically embeds the Youtube video. However, I'd like to add a custom skin to the player to match my app. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

**shot.html.erb snippit**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %>


    <p>
    <%= @song.title %> | ( <%= @song.url %> )

    <br />
    <span class="subtext"><span class="votes_<%= @song.id %>"><%= pluralize(@song.votes.count, 'like') %>,</span>
    posted <%= time_ago_in_words(@song.created_at) + " ago" %>
    <small><span class="comments"></small> | <%= pluralize(@song.comments.size, 'comment') %></span></small><br /></span></span>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%#= audio_tag (@song.track.url), controls: "controls", alt: "Please use chrome, ie, or safari", preload: :auto %>



    <iframe width="400" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<%= @video_tag %>" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always build your own HTML5 YouTube player, or use can use [this configuration page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) for some basic customization. There are also specialized services like [SublimeVideo](http://sublimevideo.net/) for creating custom HTML5 players that work with YouTube.